# Enable php on mac monterey

Tags: php, apache2, homebrew, macos-monterey

I try to install php on a mac M1 monterey, but this simple code is not interpretated :

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I installed php with brew

```
brew install php
brew link php
```

I signed the libphp module

```
codesign --sign "certificate" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

Should I use the dynamic link instead ?

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

Loading the module in the apache2.conf file

```
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.1.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so "certificate"
```

enable php page to be view in the apache2.conf file

```
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

result of `which php`

/opt/homebrew/bin//php

Is the double slash normal here ?

I can access the index.php of my web directory but php is still not executed.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this guide https://wpbeaches.com/updating-to-php-versions-7-4-and-8-on-macos-12-monterey/. . I know you probably already done most the steps but there is a section at end that mentions extra step for php8

Comment: I got frustrated with the inbuilt Apache and decided to just ditch it and go with homebrew version of Apache

Comment: Thx RyDoy ! I missed the FilesMatch section, now it's working. Yes It s been a while I try to figure out myself as I m new to mac (coming from debian) I found it quite complicated, I will keep your word for apache in case I get into new trouble (hope not) I should give you the checkmark (maybe you can make a post with the FilesMatch section, I think it will help a lot of people)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you probably done most the steps but this guide I found has one last step it mentions for PHP. Here is the link:

https://wpbeaches.com/updating-to-php-versions-7-4-and-8-on-macos-12-monterey/

Also I found a lot of my issues went away when I started using homebrew Apache instead.

I am glad the guide was able to help you get it working.

For anyone else who is stuck, here is the relevant section from the guide:

**PHP 8 and macOS Apache**

One extra step is needed for PHP 8 and macOS bundled Apache:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Add the new PHP 8 and comment out the old one.

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

Go to the end of the file and add:

```
<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Restart Apache

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes php configs are added through "other" configs if you have a line as below at the end of your httpd.conf

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

Check config files under `/private/etc/apache2/other/` and make necessary changes. I had a file called `+php-osx.conf` in that folder I edited as following:

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php@8.0/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>


<IfModule php_module>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

        <IfModule dir_module>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```